# Is Mathway wrong about the domain of $\sqrt{x-13}\sqrt{x-13}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Say $f(x) = \sqrt{x-13}$. You're trying to find the domain of $(ff)(x)$ where $$(ff)(x) = \sqrt{x-13}\sqrt{x-13}.$$

However, $\sqrt{x-13}\sqrt{x-13} = x-13 $, right?

The domain of $x-13$ in interval notation: $ (-\infty, +\infty) $

The domain of $\sqrt{x-13}$ in interval notation: $[13, +\infty) $

The domain of $\sqrt{x-13}\sqrt{x-13}$ in interval notation:

> The expression should first simplify to $x-13 $,  and we already found
>   out that   "the domain of $x-13$ in interval notation: $(-\infty,+\infty)$"

So, then, why does Mathway say that the domain of $\sqrt{x-13}\sqrt{x-13}$ is $[13, +\infty)$?

Comment: Well, it explains quite clearly what's going on. First, $\sqrt{x-13} \sqrt{x-13}$ is simplified to $x-13$, for which the domain clearly is all real numbers. (Note that this simplification is only possible if $x \geq 13$.) But this is different from the domain of $\sqrt{x-13}$.

Comment: Use LaTeX, please.

Comment: Thank you Matti, I made those observations as well. Thank you Michael, I love parentheses.

Comment: Also to clarify, I am mostly just making the observation that sqrt(x-13)*sqrt(x-13) does have a different domain than sqrt(x-13) because sqrt(x-13)*sqrt(x-13) = x - 13 which has a domain of all real numbers. Mathway informed me that the domain of sqrt(x-13)*sqrt(x-13) is [13,+∞) (in interval notation). I'm curious whether Mathway is incorrect or if I am overlooking something.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the function $\sqrt{x}:\mathbb{R}_+\to\mathbb{R}$ is defined only for $x\geq 0$. Thus, $x<13$,  the function $\sqrt{x-13}$  is undefined. Therefore, $\sqrt{x-13}\sqrt{x-13}$ is undefined. Hence, $\sqrt{x-13}\sqrt{x-13}=x-13$ only if $x\geq 13$.

It is just a matter of definition. In general, $\sqrt{\cdot}:\mathbb{R}_+\to\mathbb{R}_+$ and $(\cdot)^{1/2}:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$. So,$ (x−13)^{1/2}(x−13)^{1/2}=x−13$ always.

Comment: i appreciate the feedback! isn't sqrt(x-13)*sqrt(x-13) = x - 13 always? yes, the function sqrt(x-13) is undefined when x < 13, as the square root of a negative number is not real. but sqrt(x-13)*sqrt(x-13) is the same as saying ((sqrt(x-13))^2 right? which is just x -13? and "the domain of x-13 in interval notation: (-infinity, +infinity)" right?

Comment: It is just a matter of definition. In general, $\sqrt{x}:\mathbb{R}_+\to\mathbb{R}_+$ and $(x)^{1/2}:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$. So, $(x-13)^{1/2}(x-13)^{1/2}=x-13$ always.

Comment: that makes sense, so then shouldn't ((−13)^(1/2))*((−13)^(1/2) = −13  always have a domain of all real numbers?

Comment: I would say, yes!

Answer (score 2):

I know nothing about Mathway but I don't think that it is necessary.  It is being a little pedantic but that is necessary in maths.  If you are not careful in this way then you can "prove" all sorts of nonsense such as $1 = 0$.  Incorrect handling of square roots is common in fake proofs.

I am assuming that you are dealing with the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$.  The complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$ add different complications.  Square roots need careful handling there as well.

$$\sqrt{x - 13}\sqrt{x - 13} = x - 13$$

This is true whenever the left hand side is defined so when $x \ge 13$.  It is not true when $x < 13$ as the left hand side is not defined.

When expressions like this arise in real problems, you need to note these assumptions because they might not be apparent in the final result.  You need to treat these cases separately.  Maybe the final result is true for them as well but it requires a different proof.  Maybe it isn't even though the final result does not appear to have the restriction.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, $(ff)(x)$ means $f(x)\cdot f(x)$ in which case I think Mathway is correct. In effect you are multiplying the 'output' of a function by the 'output' of another function. You are not multiplying two expressions to make a third expression.

So, if one of the two functions has an undefined output for a given value of $x$, then the result of the multiplication must be undefined. Obviously in this case, both will have the same output for whatever value of $x$, and that will only be a defined output for $x\ge 13$.